# Construction of non-commutative torus using ergodic action of $\mathbb{T}^{n}$

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

It is well known that non-commutative torus can be constructed using universal C* algebra, by n unitary elements and twisted relations. It can also be constructed using ergodic action of torus group $\mathbb{T}^{n}$. For example, Jorgensen, Elliott and Bratteli using this construction in their [work](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1984.346.166/html).

I am interested in the details of this construction, especially the case where non-commutative torus is defined by such construction. However I cannot find much in [Rieffel's work](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Erieffel/papers/non_com_tori.pdf) nor in this article[(ERGODIC ACTIONS OF COMPACT ABELIAN GROUPS)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24713833?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents),
Can anyone point me to some reference which define non-comutative torus using such construction?

Comment: The article by Olesen–Pedersen–Takesaki *is* the canonical reference for this perspective: you’re just restricting its results to the special case where $G = \mathbb{T}^n$, so that $\hat{G} \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for point out. It seems like I overlooked it, I will take a look again.